# Deleted provisioning profile keep coming back

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I'm trying to delete a development provisioning profile that I don't need anymore, but it keeps coming back.

I tried deleting it in the developer center, but it shows up on my xCode 5.

So I went into xCode's Preferences > Accounts >  View Details and deleted it from the Provisioning Profiles section. Clicked refresh, and it was gone.

But... quit xCode, boot it up again, and the deleted provisioning profile is back. Now refresh the Provisioning Profiles page on the developer site, and it's there as well.

No matter which combination of deletions I used, first in xCode or first on the site, the provisioning profile is coming back.

Following an advice in one of threads, I installed the iPhone Configuration Utility, and deleted the provisioning profile there. It came back.

Following another thread's advice I looked for `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` in order to delete it there, but there's no such directory on my mac with OSX 10.8.5.

Any advice?

EDIT: looks like clicking the refresh button on the Preferences > Accounts > Apple ID > Provisioning Profiles is the culprit. As long as I avoid doing that, the profile doesn't come back.

I guess this is NOT really an answer, so it would still be great to get a comprehensive explanation of the issue here.

Comment: I deleted like 20 of these yesterday, and this morning they are all back. I'm pretty sure I didn't click the Refresh button, but now I'll make sure I don't. I thought Refresh only downloaded profiles from the developer site, but I guess it's shoving them up there, too.

Comment: These are coming back for me even when I'm not hitting refresh anywhere, it almost seems to be related to generating a new ad hoc build in Xcode.  Hmm.

Comment: This has been a while but I'm pretty sure I had to delete all my profiles from the developer center, and the phone I was using. All of them. Then started from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Use iPhone Configuration Utility to delete the provisioning profile.

Comment: I did. Look at my question :)

Comment: Try selecting Don't code sign option once and then try looking again. I guess the provisioning profile is cached.

Comment: It probably is cached, but where? Also I added an "Edit" to my question.

Comment: Try deleting the provisioning profile from the developer.apple.com portal. Though you have done that kindly check it once.